# How do I insert a node in a graph in sigmajs while inside angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sigma.js

**Note**: I just vastly simplified the program and have left it with the bare essentials ...

So I am trying to add graphs within a `sigma.js` graph. First, let me post the javascript (`sigmaAngualr.js`) ...

```
app = angular.module('sigmaAngular', []);

app.controller('NetworkDataCtrl', function($scope){

    var i, s; 

    $scope.newName = null;
    $scope.s = null;
    $scope.N = 3; 

    $scope.newNode = function (id, label){
        return {id: id,
                label: label,
                x: Math.random(),
                y: Math.random(),
                size: Math.random()+0.2,
                color:'#333'}
    };

    $scope.addNodeGraph = function(id, label){
        $scope.s.graph.addNode($scope.newNode(id, label));
        console.log(id+'-'+label);
    };

    $scope.tempNodes = [];
    for( i=0; i<$scope.N; i++ ) 
        $scope.tempNodes.push($scope.newNode('id'+i, 'Node'+i));

    $scope.s = new sigma({graph:{nodes:$scope.tempNodes, edges:[]}})

});

app.directive('showGraph', function(){

    // Create a link function
    function linkFunction(scope, element, attrs){
        scope.s.addRenderer({container: element[0]})
    };

    return {
        scope: false,
        link: linkFunction
    }
});
```

And here is the HTML ...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Using AngularJS</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src='lib/sigma/sigma.min.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src='lib/angular/angular.min.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src='lib/sigmaAngular.js'></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">

</head>
<body ng-app='sigmaAngular'>

    <div>
        <div ng-controller='NetworkDataCtrl'>
            <input type='text' ng-model='newName' />
            <button ng-click='addNodeGraph(newName,newName)'> Add Node </button>
            <hr>
            <div show-graph id='graph-container' s='s' tempNodes='tempNodes'>
            </div>
            <hr>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Of course, I am unable to add a node to the graph.

> I had also tried another option of creating an entire graph when I add a node. That doesnt work either. (*This is no longer true*)

Let me try to explain. Now,

1. When I refresh the browser, I do not see a graph.
2. When I *resize the browser window* The graph suddenly appears.
3. When I type a random name and hit the `Add Node` button, the graph doesnt change.
4. When I resize the browser window, the graph changes to reveal the new node.

So in summary, *I have to resize the browser window to see any changes in the graph*.

Just a side note: The css is below:

```
#graph-container {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid indianred;
}
```

I feel now that I am really close to solving the problem. Just a tiny bit off somewhere ...

Any help will be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: Could you create a fiddle/plunkr by wrapping up all?

Comment: Hi Pankja, thanks for your reply. I did try to create a new jsfiddle thing, but was unable to figure out how to add the external javascript library `sigam.js` to the fiddle. As soon as I am able to figure that out, I shall add the fiddle to the question.